# Meshes crashed memory from CharacterCustomization example

Tags: iphone, unity

I am trying the CharacterCustomization example from Unity3D which contains two scenes: Dressing room and VirtualWorld, run the VirtualWorld on iPhone, it could run but at last it will crashed, Instruments and profiler, I found the meshes are always increased and run out of memory. Anybody could help? thanks.Environment: Unity 3.4.0, Xcode 4.0.2, iOS SDK 4.3

Comment: Anybody could study the code and found the problem? It's seems multithread cause that. I want to know how to resolve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just guessing here, but the procedural meshes and/or textures it puts together probably aren't getting destroyed.

Art resources loaded at runtime in Unity cannot be garbage collected because it doesn't know that it might be used again.